# iOS Action Extension, share PDF from Safari fails

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an Action Extension to which I'm trying to share PDF-files.

I'm using the boilerplate code for `ActionRequestHandler.swift` that was autogenerated for me:

```
func beginRequest(with context: NSExtensionContext) {
    // Do not call super in an Action extension with no user interface
    self.extensionContext = context
    for item in context.inputItems as! [NSExtensionItem] {
            if let attachments = item.attachments {
                for itemProvider in attachments {
                ...
                ...
                }
             }
    }
}
```

#### Working from other apps

When exporting from every application except Safari, this is what I get:

[image: Share ok]

This is all ok, I can verify that it's an pdf by checking the `com.adobe.pdf` and then I use the `public.file-url` to fetch the shared file.

#### Failing from Safari

But when exporting from Safari (doesn't matter if I choose "Automatic" or "Pdf" for file type), I instead only get `com.apple.property-list`:

[image: share fail]

#### Further info

Both dropbox and OneDrive works, so it's doable in some sort of way.

Also I realised that sharing an PDF from a url that's protected by some sort of login doesn't work with "Public.file-url" since that URL wont be accessible from inside swift-code.

That leads me to think that the java-script preprocessor might be the way to go? Fetch the pdf-contents with JS and pass it on to code?

#### Question

How do I use the `com.apple.property-list` to fetch the file?
Or is some config I did faulty, since I get this property-list instead of the pdf/url combo?

Comment: Did you try loading item using "loadItem" with "public.file-url" identifier inside for-each loop?

Comment: Yes, I used "hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier" and it matches "public.item", "public.data" and "com.apple.property-list". I guess the two first matches are because property-list has data as superclass and "public.item" seems to be generic.

Answer (score 1):

While I didn't manage to figure out a solution to the original question, I did manage to solve the problem.

When adding an Action Extension, one gets to choose `Action type`:

- Presents user interface
- No user interface

I choosed `No user interface`since that was what I wanted.

That gave me an `Action.js` file and `ActionRequestHandler.swift`:

```
class ActionRequestHandler: NSObject, NSExtensionRequestHandling {
 ...
}
```

These files seem to work around a system where the Action.js is supposed to fetch/manipulate the source page and then send information to the backing Swift code. As stated in my original question, when sharing a PDF from Safari, no PDF-URL gets attached.

#### A working solution

If I instead choose `Presents user interface`, I got another setup, `ActionViewController.swift`:

```
class ActionViewController: UIViewController {
 
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Get the item[s] we're handling from the extension context.

    for item in self.extensionContext!.inputItems as! [NSExtensionItem] {
        for provider in item.attachments! {
            if provider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(kUTTypePDF as String) {
                provider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: kUTTypePDF as String, options: nil, completionHandler: { (pdfUrl, error) in
                    OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                            if let pdfUrl = pdfUrl as? URL {
                            // pdfUrl now contains the path to the shared pdf data
                    }
                }
          }
      }
 }
```

This file / solution works as expected, the `extensionContext` gets populated with one `attachment` that conforms to `kUTTypePDF` as expected.

Why this works, while the "no gui"-approach doesn't, I have no idea. Bug or feature?

I have not found any documentation of how/why this is supposed to work in Apple's developer section, the "share extension" documentation is very light.